# Авто pull с репозитория на сервер

Tags: git, gitlab

Есть локальный веб-сервер (windows, IIS), также локальный gitlab сервер.
Задача: при пуше в репозиторий на gitlab файлы должны автоматически обновляться на сервере.
Возможно ли реализовать и как?

Comment: Ну напишите хук в репозитории. Хотя правильный деплоймент не так, конечно, реализуется.

Answer (score 1):

Такое реализуется через pipelines https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/. Навешиваешь job на push в master, и этот джоб собирает проект, закидывает его в нужную директорию, и переключает на неё веб-сервер. Если используешь PHP, например - то могу порекомендовать https://deployer.org/.

Comment: да, у нас php, но никакие системы сборки проектов не используются. Т.е. грубо говоря нужно просто закинуть обновленные файлы на сервер

Comment: И миграций нет, и композера? В любом случае, даже просто закидывать файлы - deployer и пайплайны в помощь, это самый правильный способ